# Fastest Way to optimize this in any HTML5 or XHTML language

Tags: arrays, optimization

```
Crafty.init(500,1000, document.getElementById('game'));
//ArrayA=F2 row=i column=F7
//ArrayB=F7 row=a column=F6
//ArrayC=F6 row=LU column=F3 result
//ArrayD=F3 row=NU column=LU
//ArrayE=F9 row=1024 column=512
//ArrayF=F1 [A]=13bit [B]=9bit 

Crafty.c("Pixel",{ init: function(){ var FA=0; var FB=0; var FC=0;this.lum=128; this.i=50; this.a=50;this.NU=256; this.LU=256; this.j=0; this.b=0; this.requires("2D,Color");},
qqq: function(){ 
FC=myArrayD[this.LU][this.NU];
FB=myArrayC[this.LU][FC];
FA=myArrayB[this.a][FB];
this.b=myArrayA[this.i][FA];
this.j=myArrayE[this.y][this.x]; 
this.color("#0000FF",check.lastIndexOf(myArrayF[this.j][this.b]));

}
});

Crafty.e('2D, Canvas, Color, Pixel')
  .attr({x: 0, y: 0, w:100, h: 100})
  .color('#F00')
  //assign variables
  //The arrays are random
```

This is the Code for raytracing but I was intrested if there is anyway to speed it up for HTML5 I do NOT wan't to use a different algorithm for raytracing. Just want proper implementation of large arrays and Coloring individual pixels using something else since this is too slow as is.

Comment: `function GI(LU,NU,A,I,Y,X)
    var FC=myArrayD[LU][NU];
    var FB=myArrayC[LU][FC];
    var FA=myArrayB[A][FB];
    var b=myArrayA[I][FA];
    var j=myArrayE[Y][X]; 
    return lastIndexOf(myArrayF[this.j][this.b]))`

Comment: Something like this function may work but I think the arrays would be problematic as global variables.